# ImportError: generic_type: type "Student" is already registered

Tags: python, pybind11

I have a bit specific use-case: I have two versions of the same python binding and I want to compare their performance in the same Jupyter notebook. So, I am registering type `Student` in the binding, compiling it twice and saving in two different locations: `bindings/v1/student_py_binding.cp38-win_amd64` and `bindings/v2/student_py_binding.cp38-win_amd64`. I want to test both versions within a single Jupyter session.

Is there any workaround for the respective `ImportError` (`type is already registered!`)? Is it possible to process data with the first version of python binding, then unload the py binding (I tried to use `del sys.modules[name_of_binding]` but that did not produce the desired result), and then process data with the second version of binding? All within the same Jupyter session, without reloading the kernel?

Or the only way is to manually re-run Jupyter notebook several times, each time with different version of binding (idea is that there will be more versions than just two, so it would be cumbersome to do manually)?

Comment: Could you provide the code to reproduce the error?